# Methods setImageDrawable/setBackgroundDrawable image size issue

Tags: android, image, button, background, size

I'm having a problem with my images and buttons in Android. Basically, when i define their graphics, I use the "setImageDrawable" method. But this method makes the image enlarge and 'overfill' the view like this:

http://img36.imageshack.us/img36/7713/screenshot20120330at211.png

While what I should get is:

http://img850.imageshack.us/img850/883/screenshot20120330at214.png

The second picture is what I get when I use "setBackgroundDrawable" instead of "setImageDrawable". But it's not the right way to do it so... here is my code so you can see how I proceed:

```
        // Button "myButton" initialization
    this.btn_connexion_off_480x800 = new ImageButton(this.getContext());                                    // ImageButton instantiation
    this.btn_connexion_off_480x800.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);                               // Param√©trage du background
    this.btn_connexion_off_480x800.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_connexion_off_480x800));  // Graphic source definition
    this.btn_connexion_off_480x800.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);                                              // Param√©trage des marges int√©rieures
    this.img_header_480x800.addView(this.btn_connexion_off_480x800, new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(114, 50, 8, 12));   // Binding to the super view and setting coordinates
```

Does anyone knows why is this happening ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are setting src to some fixed layout without setting its scale type, do following:

Use ImageView instead of ImageButton, and set an extra property of imageview:

```
this.btn_connexion_off_480x800.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

Comment: Thx that solves the problem for my ImageButton. But I still have the same issue with ImageView's and the sacetype doesn't work.

Comment: imageview, please explain your problem in full details, so someone may be able to help you

Comment: Setting the scaleType solved the problem for ImageButton's. But I'm having the same problem I had for ImageButton with ImageView's except that for ImageView's, setting the scaleType doesn't work.

Comment: It might be due to you would be setting width or height parameter to wrap_content, it should be fixed one, like fill_parent, or some constant value like 50px, 50 dip, 50 sip

Comment: I basically use this code for an ImageView:

// Image "myImage" initialization
this.img_footer_480x800 = new ImageView(this.getContext());                  
  this.img_footer_480x800.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_footer_480x800));
  this.img_footer_480x800.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY); 
  this.img_background_480x800.addView(this.img_footer_480x800, new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(480, 73, 0, 689));

Answer (score 0):

Try defining a scaleType for your ImageButton with [setScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setScaleType%28android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType%29).

I would not define my layout in code try to do as much layout as possible in xml files to cleanly separate behaviour from view.

Also don't use an Absolute Layout with absolute pixel values. If you define the layout in xml use dp units as explained in the [support multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) guide. Your current layout will only work on one display size. If you are using pixel values in code you need to scale them to match the device density, this is also explained in the support multiple screens guide.

One other small improvement is the method you are using to set the drawable. An ImageButton also defines the method [setImageRessource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource%28int%29), this will allow you to directly call:

```
this.btn_connexion_off_480x800.setImageRessource(R.drawable.btn_connexion_off_480x800);
```

Comment: Sry but I'm coding my views in Java cause I can't in XML for some reasons.

Comment: Btw, I tried with "setImageRessource" and it has the same issue.

Comment: Have you tried setScaleType? Try to use something like center or centerInside as scaleType

Answer (score 0):

I tried Using XML

```
     <ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:id="@+id/Image"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="225px"
     android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

try  android:scaleType="centerCrop"

Comment: Sry but I'm coding my views in Java cause I can't in XML for some reasons.